# ACF checkbox return format based on page

Tags: plugins, php, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields checkbox and have it set to return format "both label & value". I would like to display checkbox value on the frontend except if the page is woocommerce product category, then it should output the label. I have created a shortcode in order to output the checkbox value/label in the frontend. The only problem is, that it keeps outputting "array" and not label/value as I would like it to do.

```
function hello_shortcode() { 
 
// Load field settings and values.
$field = get_field_object('producent');

if( !is_product_category() ) {
    $checkbox = $field['value'];
} else {
 $checkbox = $field['label'];
}

return $checkbox;


} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('hello', 'hello_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the output with the value. you can check the following code.

```
function hello_shortcode() { 
 
    // Load field settings and values.
    $field = get_field_object('producent');

    if( ! is_product_category() ) {
        $checkbox = $field['value'];
    } else {
        $checkbox = $field['label'];
    }

    $output = '‹p›'.$checkbox.'‹/p›';

    return $output;

} 

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('hello', 'hello_shortcode');
```